# More than one coder for gwt autobean causes AssertionError

Tags: serialization, reflection, gwt, autobean

When deserializing an autobean from JSON I get an `AssertionError` from `com.google.web.bindery.autobean.shared.impl.AutoBeanCodexImpl.CoderCreator#getCoder`. Looks like there are two types registered for my autobeans:

- my.project.model.MyAutoBean
- java.lang.Class

Of course I find the second one quite useless but I don't know where it comes from and how to get rid of it. When I disable assertions the code just works fine and (de)serializes my Autobean perfectly.

I already get two types in the initialization of the `ClientPropertyContext` but I cannot debug what in `MyAutoBean.traverseProperties` is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out on my own:

My autobean interface was extending another interface that had a method to return the AutoBean's class (to work around java type erasure in a facoty method). After removing this method it worked.